# Serialized array attribute of new model instance returns string instead of array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This is the initial migration where I set a default value:

```
class CreateMove < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :moves do |t|
      ...
      t.text :move_types, :null => false, :default => [0]
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

And this is the model:

```
class Move < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :move_types, Array
end
```

Now, when I call `Move.new`, I get the following:

```
=> #<Move id: nil, move_types: "'---\n- 0\n'">
```

But what I should be getting is

```
=> #<Move id: nil, move_types: [0]>
```

In fact, when I create a Move with `Move.create(move_types: [0])` and I fetch that move, this is what is returned!

Comment: As far as I can see move_types is a text column and text columns contain strings and not arrays. You may need to write wrappers around this columns accessors.

Comment: But isn't that supposed to be accomplished by the `serialize` method in the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in Rails. It is now fixed in Rails 4.